# user profiling and outlier detection

Tags: data-mining

I have a dataset including 1 million customers.  They are splitted into some categories like electronics customers,food and Beverage customers etc. Group names present customers' profiles.

each customer has different behaviours. For instance suppose that an electronic customer buys one electronic devices at least when he goes shopping. This transaction repeats randomly or continuously. So that I present each transaction by numerical codes.

(Value of transaction, volume of trans., transaction type, etc..) = (100,200,1)

for each transaction I have this vector above.it means every customer has a different trade behaviour.

I want to find out whether each customer has a pattern? Do we have outliers?

it is a profiling problem basically.

which analysis do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? What are you trying to get out of the analysis exactly? Buying patterns, customers that are outliers, purchases that are outliers?

If you want to determine which items are bought together, group the transactions together, just listing the items purchased at the same time and do shopping basket analysis, using the apriori algorithm or similar.

If you want to find similar customers, using k nearest neighbor or k means against a vector representing a customer's buy patterns (probably just the items bought). You can do this on individual transactions also to compare transactions.

To determine outliers, you can use a density based clustering algorithm (e.g. DBSCAN) to cluster customers together that are close to one another, and look at those customers that are not in clusters to determine outliers also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I claim that each customer has a special pattern and each vector establishes this pattern. If you have an abnormal transaction within your thousands of transactions, it effects your trade behaviour. And we name it as an outlier. It is a suspicious pattern.do i need to check whether the vectors are correlated each other?.